# How do you initialize a vector of distinct object pointers?

Tags: c++, pointers, vector

I wanted to see if I could initialize a vector of objects in a single line, so I wrote the following example:

```
vector<Bar*> bar(5, new Bar());

bar[3]->hit++;
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    cout << bar[i]->hit << endl;
```

But when I run it, I get:

```
1
1
1
1
1
```

It seems to use the same new Bar() for all the pointers. Is it possible to initialize vectors of object pointers to point to different objects?

Comment: You can, using some `std::generate` magic, but the question is, why would you want to?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All your pointers point to the same location, so the result is expected.

```
vector<Bar*> bar(5, new Bar());
```

doesn't create a new `Bar` for all 5 objects, but uses the value returned by `new Bar()`, which is a pointer to a memory location, to generate the vector.

To get the result you expect, you can use `std::generate`:

```
Bar* newBar() { return new Bar(); }

//...

vector<Bar*> bar(5);
std::generate(bar.begin(),bar.end(),newBar);
```

or simply

```
std::generate(bar.begin(),bar.end(), []{return new Bar();});
```

if C++11 is an option.

The output for this would be

```
0
0
0
1
0
```

Comment: Perfect place for a lambda if such requirements are met :)

Answer (score 1):

Initializing a vector with several different values requires C++11 and the support for initializer lists:

```
std::vector<Bar*> v { new Bar, new Bar, new Bar, new Bar };
```

You can probably use a library like Boost.Assign in versions before C++11.

Comment: Right, but please don't add Boost to your application just for this. :)

Comment: @karlphillip, you should probably add Boost anyway :P

Comment: @mauve not really, when you have `std::generate`. Also, the initialization list is an ideea, but it doesn't really work for bigger array. Imagine an array of size 100... what then?

Answer (score 0):

From the spec:

```
Effects: Constructs a vector with n copies of value [...]
```

where n is the first and value the second argument.